# How to find a large-amount of sample-dummy files

Tags: zip, compression, data-analysis

I'm currently working on a data analysis which I need to compress a huge amount of different files (like a real file system with installed OS and user files and programs).

To test the software, I need to do several tests, however, I couldn't find a database or collection of data which includes a large amount of dummy data/folders to be similar to a real file system.
This collection of files can include any file type, like text files, office files, images, videos etc. with several folders of course to show this dummy collection is likely to be a real case.

If there is any collection like this I appreciate any hint.

Comment: Aren't you developing your code on a computer with a real file system with an installed OS and user files and programs? Simply use your own, actual, file system.

Comment: Hi @Mark Adler, Thanks for your comment, but obviously I don't want to shoot on my leg and destroy my own OS every time I test and debug the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can download filesystems for Linux-based distributions for example if you want to download the file structure of ubuntu, you can go to https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/focal/release/ and download the file that ends with the root.tar.xz like

```
$ wget https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz
```

Extract the file. (You may need to run this command as sudo):

```
$ tar -xf ubuntu-20.04-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz ubuntu-fs
```

and now you have a file system of ubuntu 20.04

Like this, you can download file systems of other distributions too.
Let me know if I understood your problem and answered your query correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I'm looking for is mostly an installed file system, which contains regular user files and OS files, User files like videos, images, office file, for instance a video folder with bunch of dummy videos, a photo folder with thousands of dummy photos, and lot of office/text file in a Document folder... sth like this as a data collection sample.